# Was pink a boy color and blue a girl color prior to the 20th century?

Tags: united-states, gender, colors

A recent essay in the *New York Times* by Claire Cain Miller, entitled [How to Raise a Feminist Son](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/02/upshot/how-to-raise-a-feminist-son.html?_r=0), claims that:

> Until the mid-20th century, pink was the boy color and blue was for
>   girls.

It, in turn, cites an Ask Smithsonian [blog post](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/arts-culture/when-did-girls-start-wearing-pink-1370097/?no-ist) by Jeanne Maglaty.

How well-grounded in the historical evidence is this claim?

Comment: [Well sourced section on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink#Gender). Seems to be true.

Comment: Further investigation turned up this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229437155_The_Twentieth_Century_Reversal_of_Pink-Blue_Gender_Coding_A_Scientific_Urban_Legend. It is a little puzzling why this isn't mentioned in the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Please remember to restrict this kind of question to a sensible domain (e.g. United States). There's no reason why different cultures can't have different gendered colors, or different histories of them.

Comment: @Sklivvz This article discussing Naples, Italy in 1889 says pink blouse for boys, blue blouse for girls: https://books.google.com/books?id=YM1TAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA187#v=onepage&q=pink&f=false

Comment: @DavePhD interesting, yet irrelevant to my point.

Comment: @Sklivvz It's not *irrelevant*, it helps determine what the "sensible domain" ought to be.

Comment: @KyleStrand that is incorrect: a "sensible domain" is determined by having one only possible answer *in theory*, not by retrofitting the domain after the possible answers. It could be cherry picked evidence.

Comment: @Sklivvz That's fair--I originally misread DavePhD's comment as a reference to the OP ("The article discusses...") rather than a citation of an unrelated article. Still, since the OP doesn't specify a "sensible domain", presumably the domain selected should be reasonably broad, and if Italy a mere decade before the start of the 20th century is an interesting data point, then restricting answers to the United States seems unreasonably narrow.

Comment: @Sklivvz after much search of old newspapers, the oldest US mention of the "pink for boys, blue for girls" tradition is in an 1888 article "Styles here and abroad", and the article says it is based upon a Berlin fashion journal that "is considered the fashion autocrat of Paris, London, Berlin, Vienna, and New York".  (Maybe "Seasons" is the title or translated title of the journal, February issue.) I think when people say it was a tradition, they mean a tradition from Europe.  Several other US articles specify France, and one says it is from Dutch tradition.

Comment: See also http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2831/was-pink-originally-the-color-for-boys-and-blue-for-girls

Comment: Blue has been used in babies since the pharaohs.  Its about protection against the devil. Also the Babylon and Hebrew talked about it.   And what's about pink?.   Its just a vogue for girls.  So then, for boy, the color never changed. For girls, its just the fancy of the moment.

Comment: @magallanes you got any citations for those claims?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

According to the 1930 version of Stack Exchange, [Popular Questions Answered](https://books.google.com/books?id=ty9HAAAAIAAJ&q=baby%20girls%20pink&dq=baby%20girls%20pink&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAvLKL-6fUAhUKi1QKHYReBiwQ6AEIJjAA):

> **What are the clothing colors for baby boys and girls?**
>
> According to a traditional color scheme, which is of unknown origin, baby boys are properly dressed in pink clothing and baby girls in blue, although in some parts of the country, particularly in the Southern States, this symbolical color arrangement is reversed and baby boys are dressed in blue and girls in pink. One writer says that blue was assigned to girls because that was the color assigned to the Virgin Mary and the royal house of David to which she belonged. At any rate, blue and pink have become associated with babies. When friends are notified that the stork has paid a visit to a home the announcement cards are often decorated with blue ribbons if the baby is a girl, and with pink ribbons if it is a boy. Apparently, however, this traditional color arrangement based on the sex of the child is giving way to more practical considerations. In the issue of *Forecast* for May, 1927, Mollie Amos Polk says on this subject : "According to the buyer of one of the most famous shops pink and blue are now used interchangeably for boys and girls. Pink, however, since it is universally becoming and will stand frequent tubbings, is much more popular for both."

According to the 8 October 1914 Shoe and Leather Reporter article [Children's Shoe Fashions for Spring and Summer 1915](https://books.google.com/books?id=wek-AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA23&dq=baby%20boys%20pink%20baby%20girls%20blue&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw-LDsgajUAhWIqlQKHSP3CC4Q6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=baby%20boys%20pink%20baby%20girls%20blue&f=false):

> shoes trimmed with blue for baby boys, and pink for baby girls are shown in the spring samples

Like fredsbend commented, there are lists of additional sources [on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_historical_sources_for_pink_and_blue_as_gender_signifiers).  Sources saying "blue for girls, pink for boys" can be found up to about 1941; however, it was not a strong tradition.  During the same time period, as the above shoe reference shows, people also dressed boys in blue and girls in pink.

Another clear counter-example is the article [Women's Part in the New Renaissance](https://books.google.com/books?id=FbcGAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA893&dq=traditional%20colors%20blue%20boys%20pink%20girls&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjolNn5kanUAhXIKWMKHYpvC8EQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=traditional%20colors%20blue%20boys%20pink%20girls&f=false) *Century Magazine*, April 1923:

> Mothers take good care to discover the suitable color and adornment for their little ones, blue for the little boy, pink for the little girl...

The strongest evidence I can find for a tradition of pink for boys, blue for girls, is that there was criticism of president McKinley's wife for sending  blue booties to former president Cleveland's wife on the occasion of a boy being born:

> **as all the world which has had experience in such things knows, blue boots are for girls and pink for boys**

[Omaha Daily Bee](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn99021999/1897-11-07/ed-1/seq-19/#date1=1789&sort=date&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=18&words=blue+boys+girls+pink&proxdistance=10&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=boys+blue+girls+pink&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=2) 7 November 1897 (similar articles 6 November 1897 in [Desert Evening News](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045555/1897-11-06/ed-1/seq-3/#date1=1789&sort=date&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=17&words=blue+boy+girl+pink&proxdistance=10&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=boys+blue+girls+pink&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=2), the [Salt Lake Herald](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85058130/1897-11-06/ed-1/seq-4/#date1=1789&sort=date&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=8&words=Baby+blue+boys+girls+pink&proxdistance=50&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=baby+blue+girl+pink+boy&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=2) and [Blackfoot News](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn88056017/1897-11-06/ed-1/seq-4/#date1=1789&sort=date&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=10&words=baby+blue+Blue+boys+girls+pink&proxdistance=50&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=baby+blue+girl+pink+boy&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=2))

Additional articles recommending pink for boys, blue for girls include:

The earliest article, [Styles Here and Abroad](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83030272/1888-01-09/ed-1/seq-5/#date1=1789&sort=relevance&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=6&words=blues+boy+girls+Pinks+red&proxdistance=10&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=pink+red+boys+blue+girls+&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=2), The Sun, New York, 09 January 1888:

> Pinks and reds are the colors for boy babies, blues and creams for girls

[A Word about Babies: Appropriate gifts](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn90059522/1889-10-22/ed-1/seq-6/#date1=1789&sort=date&date2=1924&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=3&words=blue+boys+girls+pink&proxdistance=5&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=pink+boy+blue+girl&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) St. Paul Daily Globe 22 October 1889 (the advice spread to several other newspapers a month later, the [Hickman Courier](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85052141/1889-11-22/ed-1/seq-1/#date1=1789&sort=date&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=7&words=boys+pink&proxdistance=10&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=pink+for+boys&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=2), the [Ohio Democrat](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn87075048/1889-11-23/ed-1/seq-3/#date1=1789&sort=date&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=8&words=boys+pink&proxdistance=10&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=pink+for+boys&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=2) and the [Macon Beacon](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83016943/1889-11-23/ed-1/seq-1/#date1=1789&sort=date&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=9&words=boys+pink&proxdistance=10&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=pink+for+boys&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=2)):

> pink for boys, blue for girls, the gossip says

[About Fall Fashions](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045462/1890-09-20/ed-1/seq-8/#date1=1789&sort=date&date2=1924&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=4&words=blue+boy+girl+pink&proxdistance=5&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=pink+boy+blue+girl&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) Evening Star, Washington, 20 September 1890 (same article [in Indianapolis Journal](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn82015679/1890-09-21/ed-1/seq-10/#date1=1789&sort=date&date2=1924&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=5&words=blue+boy+girl+pink&proxdistance=5&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=pink+boy+blue+girl&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1)):

> white ribbon for the first three months, afterward pink for a boy, blue for a girl-clover pink for a blonde boy and very pale blue for a dark baby girl

[Article](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83030272/1892-07-03/ed-1/seq-17/#date1=1789&sort=date&date2=1924&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=7&words=blue+boy+girl+pink&proxdistance=5&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=pink+boy+blue+girl&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) in The Sun, New York 03 July 1892:

> pink for a boy, blue for a girl, according to French fashion

[Baby's Wardrobe](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn97065075/1893-09-29/ed-1/seq-2/#date1=1789&sort=date&date2=1924&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=8&words=blue+boy+girl+Pink&proxdistance=5&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=pink+boy+blue+girl&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) Lawrence Democrat 29 September 1893:

> "Pink for a boy and blue for a girl" is a generally accepted dictum

[For Small Fry](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85058130/1896-04-19/ed-1/seq-12/#date1=1789&sort=date&date2=1924&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=17&words=baby+Blue+blue+boys+girls+Pink&proxdistance=50&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=baby+boy+pink+girl+blue&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) Salt Lake Herald, but with New York dateline, 19 April 1896 (also published in [The Morning Times](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn84024442/1896-04-19/ed-1/seq-20/#date1=1789&sort=date&date2=1924&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=18&words=baby+Blue+blue+boys+girl+Pink&proxdistance=50&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=baby+boy+pink+girl+blue&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1), Washington, and days later with the title [For Small Children](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85025715/1896-04-25/ed-1/seq-8/#date1=1789&sort=date&date2=1924&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=19&words=baby+Blue+blue+boys+girl+Pink&proxdistance=50&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=baby+boy+pink+girl+blue&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) in the Norfolk Virginian):

> Pink pique is also used for small gentleman in the baby stages...
> Blue being a girl's color the sky blue pique is not used for boys

[Article](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn99021999/1896-07-26/ed-1/seq-11/#date1=1789&sort=date&date2=1924&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=10&words=blue+boy+girl+pink&proxdistance=5&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=pink+boy+blue+girl&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) Omaha Daily Bee 26 July 1896 ([same article](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85058130/1896-07-26/ed-1/seq-15/#date1=1789&sort=date&date2=1924&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=11&words=blue+boy+girl+pink&proxdistance=5&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=pink+boy+blue+girl&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) in Salt Lake Herald ):

> generally pink for a boy and blue for a girl

[Article](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn84020358/1900-03-01/ed-1/seq-4/#date1=1789&sort=date&date2=1924&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=13&words=blue+boy+girl+pink&proxdistance=5&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=pink+boy+blue+girl&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) in The Daily Morning Journal and Courier, New Haven, 01 March 1900:

> it's pink for a boy and blue for a girl

[An Arbitrary Rule](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn84038095/1902-07-29/ed-1/seq-2/#date1=1789&sort=date&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=18&words=blue+boys+girl+pink&proxdistance=10&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=pink+girl+blue+boy&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=3) The Denison review, 29 July 1902 (also published in [The Columbus Commercial](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn87065028/1902-08-12/ed-1/seq-6/#date1=1789&sort=date&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=19&words=blue+boys+girl+pink&proxdistance=10&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=pink+girl+blue+boy&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=3), the [Willmar Tribune](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn89081022/1902-08-13/ed-1/seq-3/#date1=1789&sort=date&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=0&words=blue+boys+girl+pink&proxdistance=10&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=pink+girl+blue+boy&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=4), the [Barbour County Index](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn82015080/1902-08-20/ed-1/seq-2/#date1=1789&sort=date&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=2&words=blue+boys+girl+pink&proxdistance=10&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=pink+girl+blue+boy&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=4), and [The Columbian](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83032011/1902-08-28/ed-1/seq-2/#date1=1789&sort=date&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=3&words=blue+boys+girl+pink&proxdistance=10&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=pink+girl+blue+boy&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=4)):

> you know blue is only for girl babies, pink's for boys.-Philadelphia Press

[Sending Christmas Gifts](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn99062049/1906-12-21/ed-1/seq-14/#date1=1789&index=0&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=baby+blue+boy+gift+girl+pink&proxdistance=50&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=baby+gift+boy+blue+girl+pink&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) Sisseton Weekly Standard, 21 December 1906:

> If you are sending a gift to a baby, tie it up with blue ribbons if the baby is a girl, pink ribbons if it is a boy

[Blue for Girls](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn88084272/1912-12-11/ed-1/seq-6/#date1=1789&sort=date&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=1&words=babies+baby+blue+BLUE+boy+boys+girl+girls+pink&proxdistance=50&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=baby+boy+blue+girl+pink&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=11) El Paso Herald, 11 December 1912:

> Dear Miss Fairfax: To settle an argument ... what colors are used for babies..."
>
> ...custom has given blue to the girl baby and pink to the boy.

[Birth Announcements](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn90061308/1913-02-14/ed-1/seq-7/#date1=1789&index=1&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=announce+ANNOUNCEMENTS+blue+boys+girls+pink&proxdistance=50&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=announcements+boys+blue+girls+pink&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) [The Monett Time](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn90061308/1913-02-14/ed-1/seq-7/#date1=1789&index=1&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=announce+ANNOUNCEMENTS+blue+boys+girls+pink&proxdistance=50&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=announcements+boys+blue+girls+pink&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1)s 14 February 1913:

> For boys a pink border, for girls a light blue

[Baby Books](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn84022472/1913-03-17/ed-1/seq-10/#date1=1789&sort=date&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=7&words=baby+Baby+blue+boys+girls+pink&proxdistance=50&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=baby+boy+blue+girl+pink&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=11) Bridgeport Evening Farmer 17 March 1913:

> blue for girls and pink for boys

After a reader disagreed with columnist Cynthia Grey's (pseudonym) advice "pink for a boy, blue for a girl", Grey [responded](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn88085187/1916-11-28/ed-1/seq-4/#date1=1789&index=0&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=blue+boys+Dutch+girls+Pink+pink&proxdistance=10&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=blue+boy+pink+girl+dutch&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) in The Tacoma Times 28 November 1916:

> According to the authorities at the public library...Pink is for boys and blue for girls.  This is an old Dutch custom.  When a boy was born a pink ball was hung out and when a girl was born a blue ball was displayed.

So in conclusion, though numerous sources can be found starting around 1888 saying that "pink for a boy and blue for a girl" is traditional, others expressed that the tradition was visa versa.

A quantitative study was done in 1921.  See [Correct Color for Birth Card Announcements](https://books.google.com/books?id=MCgdAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA4-PA18&dq=%22pink%20for%20a%20boy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj664is37DUAhVEFj4KHVRLBRAQ6AEILDAC#v=onepage&q=%22pink%20for%20a%20boy%22&f=false) in volume 89 of *The American Stationary and Office Outfitter*, 6 August 1921, page 18:

> Our questionnaire replies showed cities totaling 12,000,000 people using blue for a boy, cities totaling 6,000,000 using pink for a boy.

The study was conducted by the National Association of Steel and Copper Engravers with the stated purpose of standardizing the colors and was published in several other journals, such as [Geyer's Stationer](https://books.google.com/books?id=Xpk7AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA56&dq=%22pink%20for%20a%20boy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj664is37DUAhVEFj4KHVRLBRAQ6AEIMTAD#v=onepage&q=%22pink%20for%20a%20boy%22&f=false); [Dry Goods Economist](https://books.google.com/books?id=SMVFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA105&dq=%22pink%20for%20a%20boy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj664is37DUAhVEFj4KHVRLBRAQ6AEIOzAF#v=onepage&q=%22pink%20for%20a%20boy%22&f=false); [Walden's Stationer and Printer](https://books.google.com/books?id=QKRAAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA3-PA58&dq=%22pink%20for%20a%20boy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj664is37DUAhVEFj4KHVRLBRAQ6AEINjAE#v=onepage&q=%22pink%20for%20a%20boy%22&f=false) and [Modern Stationer and Book-Seller](https://books.google.com/books?id=ruc_AQAAMAAJ&pg=PT749&dq=%22pink%20for%20a%20boy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj664is37DUAhVEFj4KHVRLBRAQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=%22pink%20for%20a%20boy%22&f=false)

Comment: In Belgium, until at least 1970 when I left there, blue was the colour for girls, as it was the colour of the virgin Mary. I don't remember if there was a specific colour for boys - I certainly don't remember being dressed in pink...

Comment: @hdhondt This 28 March 1884 newspaper article says that in France for birth announcements "For a boy they are pale blue, for a girl delicate pink".  http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83025001/1884-03-28/ed-1/seq-8/#date1=1789&index=2&date2=1924&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=blue+boy+girl+pink&proxdistance=10&state=&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=boy+blue+girl+pink&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1

Comment: I wonder if the "blue for girls because Virgin Mary" was a Catholic thing.  It would explain why it never took hold in the South ([low percentage](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/2015/09/150917-data-points-how-catholic-population-has-shifted-in-the-united-states) of Catholics).  It would also explain the Belgium comment.

Comment: Keep in mind that blue for girls and pink for boys does not seem to be nearly as common in English-speaking countries. In Wikipedia's list of historical sources for pink and blue as gender signifiers https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_historical_sources_for_pink_and_blue_as_gender_signifiers almost if not every English-language source up until 1940 says blue for boys and pink for girls. I do think the few examples of the opposite are from people used to Catholic traditions.

Comment: @JackArbiter I added two 1897 newspaper articles showing that the "pink for boys, blue for girls" applied even to non-Catholics.  I don't think Wikipedia has these sources.

Comment: Blue is natural colour for girls because of the virgin Mary indeed, but pink also makes sense for boys as it is a lighter version of red which is to this day the manlier colour (colour of patricians in antiquity, colour of blood and war, action and force).

Comment: @Shautieh Violet was even better. It was a very expensive dye before modern organic dyes, reserved for the highest orders. It actually *brightened* rather than fading with use. Funny how today both red and purple are seen as girlish :)

Comment: @Luaan Violet is the colour of penance and mourning though. But yes expensive dyes made those colours particularly valuable.

Comment: This answer is **basically wrong** and MDG's answer is basically correct.  1 - it all comes from Paoletti.  2 - she assert it was ***inconsistent*** before 1950.   3 - the rest is pure urban myth.

Comment: @Fattie Paoletti is correct, it was inconsistent before 1950.  I can find numerous references between 1880 and 1940 that say pink for boys and blue for girls, and numerous references in the same time period that say blue for boys and pink for girls.

Comment: I think this answer could be improved with the addition of a clear conclusion, such as "It is not true that pink was a boy color and blue was a boy color prior to the 20th century, but rather the use of these colors was inconsistent..." or something to that effect.

Comment: @JaysonVirissimo I want to add more non-Wikipedia examples from newspapers, then I'll write a conclusion like that.  Definitely there were some people who thought pink for boys was traditional, and others thought blue for boys was appropriate, and still others would write to newspaper editors asking what was correct.

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that there wasn't a reversal of conventional colors for girls and boys, but that a strong convention only developed during the 20th century?

Comment: @JaysonVirissimo yes, but I think it would better to say after 1940.  There are references up to about 1941 saying pink for boys.  "Analytical sociology" (1955) says "Each sex is even supposed to have a distinctive color: blue for boys, pink for girls. " So I would say it was set some time between 1940 and 1955.  https://books.google.com/books?id=_dA9AAAAYAAJ&q=%22blue+for+boys%22+%22pink+for+girls%22&dq=%22blue+for+boys%22+%22pink+for+girls%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJvqfG3a7UAhUIMSYKHZAVCC0Q6AEINjAF

Comment: My suggested conclusion would be that (a) there is no evidence that a complete reversal took place, as usually told in media reports etc.; and (b) there is evidence of inconsistent gender coding before the 1940s-50s (which accords with paoletti's account), but exactly how strong the inconsistency was is unclear. There are several instances of inconsistent coding in newspapers, but books (via Ngram) return a more uniform picture.

Comment: @MDG Check out these Ngrams. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blue+for+girls%2Cblue+for+boys&year_start=1880&year_end=1940&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblue%20for%20girls%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cblue%20for%20boys%3B%2Cc0 Del Giudice denies finding any hits for "blue for girls".

Comment: @DavePhD: the reason you're finding some hits for "blue for girls" is that you're using the 2012 Ngram database, which is the default now but wasn't available in early 2012 (at the time there was only the 2009 database). Repeating the search on the 2009 Am Eng database will return zero hits, as reported. These details are reported in the 2012 letter.

Comment: @MDG Fortunately, a quantitative study was done in 1921, and found "blue for a boy" was preferred 2:1 over "pink for a boy".  I added to answer.  The widely published study makes very clear that there was no accepted standard nationally, and that the purpose of the study was to try to determine and standardize to the majority opinion.

Comment: @DavePhD I upvoted the answer due to finding that awesome study and coming to this final conclusion. Occasionally Stack Exchange drives a dedicated user to do so much research and provide so much evidence that an answer provides a more complete picture than any actual piece of scholarship, and it's always great to see. I would suggest (just my own preference) providing a summary of your conclusion up front, since the ample quotations crowd out the final summary.

Comment: I went ahead and pinged Jeanne Maglaty via twitter in case she knows of any sources we aren't referencing yet. I'll hold off on accepting an answer until she has a chance to respond.

Comment: @JaysonVirissimo There are more articles saying pink for boy, blue for girl in the Chronicling America database.  I listed most of the ones before 1900, but only some of the ones after 1900 (since your question was "prior to the 20th century").  And if someone looked in https://www.newspapers.com/ they would find many more.  The easiest way to find more references would be to do the free trial registration at newspapers.com and search there.

Comment: @JaysonVirissimo This book is saying Belgium was "blue for a girl, pink for a boy" as of 1929: https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=r-geAwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PR7&dq=%22pink+for+a+boy%22&ots=Jd2QDok8dp&sig=xFWNpV6bj04ZDJGzObcpILi4JAM#v=onepage&q=%22pink%20for%20a%20boy%22&f=false I added a few more early 20th century examples to the answer from the Chronicling America database.  The database is only through 1924 though.

Comment: Marked as answered, but think this could still use some re-organization and more prominent summary of the conclusion.

Comment: Could you add a tl;dr; please?

Answer (score 48):

This claim originated in a [1987 paper](http://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/494390?journalCode=signs) by Jo Paoletti, a researcher in American Studies, and was presented in expanded form in a [2012 book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Pink_and_Blue.html?id=HPyIoreJ1jIC) by the same author. In these publications, Paoletti did not argue that pink and blue had been *reversed*, but only that their use had been *inconsistent* prior to the 1950s. It is unclear how and when this initial argument morphed into the popular,  widely repeated idea that the gender associations of pink and blue were uniformly reversed in the early 20th century. While some text fragments found by Paoletti and others are compatible with a scenario of inconsistent gender norms, the idea of a complete reversal has no basis in historical evidence and seems to have spread as a sort of urban legend, eventually making its way into the scientific literature (see [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229437155_The_Twentieth_Century_Reversal_of_Pink-Blue_Gender_Coding_A_Scientific_Urban_Legend) for examples and discussion).

In a [2012 letter to Archives of Sexual Behavior](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229437155_The_Twentieth_Century_Reversal_of_Pink-Blue_Gender_Coding_A_Scientific_Urban_Legend), Marco Del Giudice performed a Google NGram search in English language books (US and UK) from 1880 to 1980 and found no evidence of inconsistent usage during this period; in contrast, there were many instances of the familiar female-pink and male-blue associations. Based on this finding, the author suggested that the text fragments that are usually cited in support of Paoletti's claim may have been unrepresentative of the cultural norms of the time, or (at least in some instances) have other, less obvious explanations (e.g., misprints, satire).

Jo Paoletti and biologist Anne Fausto-Sterling replied to the letter in a [Huffington Post article](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/dr-anne-fausto-sterling/ive-got-those-evidentiary-blues-and-pinks_b_1840780.html), although they did not provide additional evidence. In the same article they challenged previous speculations that sex-related preferences for pink and blue may be partially rooted in biological processes.

Note: to date, the issue of a possible biological basis for pink/blue preferences remains unresolved. The relevant peer-reviewed literature includes:

- A [2007 paper by Hurlbert and Ling](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S096098220701559X) that found a pattern of sex-differentiated color preferences in different regions of the visible spectrum (blue-green vs. reddish-purple);
- A [2014 paper by Sorokowski et al.](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Piotr_Sorokowski/publication/260382312_Sex_differences_in_color_preferences_transcend_extreme_differences_in_culture_and_ecology) that found similar sex-differentiated preferences for colors (along a blue vs. red-purple axis) in Poland and in the Yali of Papua New Guinea;
- A [2015 paper by Wong and Hines](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Wang_Ivy_Wong/publication/272295913_Preferences_for_Pink_and_Blue_The_Development_of_Color_Preferences_as_a_Distinct_Gender-Typed_Behavior_in_Toddlers) that found no robust associations between color preferences and other sex-typed preferences (e.g., toys) in toddlers.

UPDATE (June 23, 2017): Here is a link to a [new letter in Archives of Sexual Behavior](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317832997_Pink_blue_and_gender_An_update) (Del Giudice, 2017). The letter updates the 2012 Ngram search and supplements it with information about newspapers/magazines from Chronicling America and Wikipedia. It also reviews recent studies of sex differences in color preferences and summarizes current evolutionary hypotheses in this area.

Comment: The Ngram evidence seems much stronger to me that any handful of anecdotes cited on wikipedia or in the media, but the biological claims are probably beyond the scope of and unnecessary for answering this question.

Comment: @JaysonVirissimo Ngram will only give info from googlebooks, there is much more information in newspaper databases.

Comment: When del Giudice relies on NGram, the problem is how he interprets a hit for "pink for a girl".  For example if he read the actual 1888 reference represented in the Ngram, it says " It has long been an accepted fact that pink for girls of your colouring is inadmissible. Fair ones with golden locks must content themselves with blue" https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22blue+for+boys%22#tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&tbm=bks&q=%22pink+for+girls%22&spf=1496932345161 Del Giudice is wrong, only found at most 5 pre-1900 hits in Ngram, and wrongly relied on them.

Comment: @MDG, its worth nodding to sds' russian sources, as it establishes some older timelines on these color associations.

Comment: @DavePhD: the assumption was not that each individual Ngram hit represents a statement of gender norms. In this kind of search there is going to be noise and a number of irrelevant hits. The point is comparative, i.e., the fact that opposite-coding search phrases (e.g., "pink for a boy") returned no hits at all. It is hard to reconcile this overall pattern with the existence of widespread opposite conventions.

Comment: Also @DavePhD: Maybe a fine point, but the quotation in your comment doesn't appear to contradict the standard gender norm. It seems to imply that pink would be preferable for girls ("content themselves") but can't be used in this specific case because of the skin/hair color. That said, a lot of quotations like this one are going to require a certain amount of interpretation (e.g., some quotes on pink/blue I found in newspapers might be read as ironic); the advantages of "blind" large-scale searches (e.g., on Ngram) is that they will smooth out some of this noise.

Comment: @MDG The problem is the Ngram search is finding too few references in the 1888-1900 time period to make any statement at all.  I list 16 references in just that 13 year period clearly saying pink for boys, blue for girls.  And I could add more.

Comment: @JaysonVirissimo: fully agree, the biological claims are not necessary to answer the historical question. I noted them for the opposite reason--the assumed reversal of gender norms in the 20th century has been used by some to deny the possibility of a biological component in color preferences (e.g., Cordelia Fine in her 2010 book). So I thought it might be worthwhile to make a note about it.

Comment: @DavePhD: I'm not doubting that there are references pointing to the existence of opposite coding. I don't think I made strong statements about the pre-1900 era in particular; Ngram returns many more hits in the period 1900-1940 (when conventions were supposedly inconsistent or even reversed), and the pattern is the same. Anybody arguing that conventions were reversed/strongly inconsistent prior to 1940-50 should be able to explain the complete asymmetry in the Ngram database. "Chance" might work for the few references prior to 1900, but later on?

Comment: One more general note: at the time of the 2012 letter, most people only cited the same 4-5 newspaper fragments. People have been digging up many more quotations since (the wikipedia page on historical sources is quite new).

Comment: @MDG you're saying zero google book hits for "pink for a boy" https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pink+for+a+boy%22&biw=573&bih=420&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1880%2Ccd_max%3A1940&tbm=bks ?

Comment: @DavePhD: As you can imagine, Google Books keeps expanding its coverage by the day, so you might find stuff today that wasn't there in 2012. Also, Ngram does not search in the whole of Google Books--it uses a specially compiled database. E.g., the current database was compiled in 2012. In early 2012, the only database available for Ngram searches was the one complied in 2009.

Comment: If you search "pink for a boy" on Ngram using the American English 2009 database (or even the 2012 one) you will get zero hits, as reported. Searching Google Books directly will return more hits (because of the larger database), but will not give you frequency data, which is the point of Ngram.

Comment: At the cost of belaboring the point: I never claimed that there are no instances of reversed gender coding in books or elsewhere. That would be delusional--there clearly are such instances. I claimed that: (a) Ngram did not return any hits with the 2009 database (true and easy to verify);

Comment: and (b) the proportion of standard vs. reversed instances of gender coding in books is extremely asymmetric (true, even in the larger 2012 database), which challenges the idea that gender norms were markedly inconsistent before the 1940s-50s.

Answer (score 21):

Not in Russia - boys/blue & girls/red association has been around for 200+ years.

The Soviet/Russian official theory is ([wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)/[source](http://www.vokrugsveta.ru/quiz/504/)):

> Обычай перевязывать новорождённых **мальчиков** **голубой** лентой, а новорождённых **девочек** **красной** восходит к вышеупомянутому указу Павла I награждать каждого родившегося великого князя при крещении орденом Святого Андрея Первозванного, а великих княжон — орденом Святой Екатерины

Translation:

> The custom to tie newborn **boys** with a **blue** ribbon (and **red** ribbon for **girls**) stem from the law that every [Grand Duke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Grand_Dukes_of_Russia) is decorated with the [Order of St. Andrew the Apostle the First-Called](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_St._Andrew) at christening (and every [Grand Duchess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Grand_Duchesses_of_Russia) is decorated with the [Order of Saint Catherine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_Saint_Catherine)).

The St.Andrew ribbon is blue, St.Catherine ribbon is red.

The aforementioned law is the statute of the Order of St. Andrew signed by [Paul I of Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_I_of_Russia) on 1797-04-16.

Comment: How old is this law? Is it from before or after we have evidence of this color mapping from literature?

Comment: @JaysonVirissimo: 1797-04-16 (see edit)

Comment: That's quite the find, especially given that it has roots in christendom, which allows for the possibility that this viewpoint could've leaked throughout Europe quite rapidly.

Comment: This 1916 US newspaper also mentions that pink for girl, blue for boy, is a Russian tradition.  http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn88077067/1916-06-02/ed-1/seq-7/#date1=1789&index=2&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=baby+Baby+blue+boy+Girl+girl+Pink+pink&proxdistance=50&date2=1924&ortext=&proxtext=pink+boy+baby+girl+blue&phrasetext=&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1

Answer (score 2):

In an episode of QI ([youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9iYvSztyHs)) they address this, [their website](http://qi.com/infocloud/gender) I will quote below:

> Until the 20th century toddlers of either sex were normally dressed in white, but when colours were used, boys were dressed in pink. At the turn of the 20th century, Dressmaker Magazine wrote: 'The preferred colour to dress young boys in is pink. Blue is reserved for girls as it is considered paler, and the more dainty of the two colours, and pink is thought to be stronger (akin to red).' As late as 1927, Time magazine reported that Princess Astrid of Belgium had been caught out when she gave birth to a girl, because 'The cradle…had been optimistically outfitted in pink, the colour for boys.'

Comment: And QI [never gets anything wrong](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/tv/news/stephen-fry-quits-qi-8-facts-the-show-got-wrong-according-to-its-broadcaster-dave-a6693921.html).